# Columns not displaying in TableView - java

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am trying to write a programm that displays the content of a table in a database in a javafx gui using a TableView. I have a generic gui that has an empty TableView in it. After you decide what table you want to display the application send the table name to the middleware which gets all the column names from the database and sends them bakc to the application.Then i loop over all the column names, generate a new TableColumn and add it to the TableView and call the `refresh()` method of TableView. Using `table.getChidlren();` I can see that the columns were successfully added to the TableView, however they are not displayed in the JavaFX GUI whatsoever. It just keeps displaying "No columns in table". All the fx:ids and controller classes are correct too.

Here is my code:

```
public void loadTableContent(){
    try (Socket client = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 667);
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
         ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream())) {

        System.out.println("Sending request");
        oos.writeUTF(databaseTableComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
        oos.flush();

        System.out.println("reading from sever");
        String[] columnNames =  ois.readUTF().split(";");

        System.out.println("Column names received");

        for (String s: columnNames)
            table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn(s));

        table.refresh();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: check if columnNames really is an array of length > 0. If all goes well, there's no need for table.refresh - if it makes a difference, something is wrong with your setup. Anyway, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: "I can see that the columns were successfully added to the TableView, however they are not displayed in the JavaFX GUI whatsoever." How do you see they were added to the table view but not displayed were gonna need more information to solve this

Comment: I used the table.getColumns() method and iterated over the elements. All of the columns were there but they did not show up in the GUI.

Comment: What thread is `loadTableContent` called on? The _JavaFX Application Thread_ or some background thread? If it's the latter then that could be causing your issue—never update a live scene-graph from a thread other than the _JavaFX Application Thread_.

Comment: It is called in the JavaFX Application Thread

Comment: Are you sure the the `table` you're adding the columns to **is** the same `TableView` that is displayed in your UI?  Without the complete code, we can only guess at what is going wrong...

Comment: Yes it is indeed the same TableView, I made sure to doublecheck all of these possibilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I added the TableView in SceneBuilder, however I called `table = new TableView();` in my Code which just erased the one from SceneBuilder. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: which is missing from your snippet - had it been there, some eyes might have spotted it earlier ;) that's why an [mcve] is important ..